# How to assign value as a function to an object without quotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to generate very large Javascript files with node. Each one of them contains a const variable which assists for right values at the file (which I can know their values only on runtime). 
Example:

```
'use strict'
const lib = require('myLib')
const language = lib.getMyLang()
module.exports = {
    "type": lib.getType(language),
    "info": lib.getInfo(language),
    "title": lib.getTitle(language)
}
```

When I've tried to generate it, I got the values as strings:

```
'use strict'
const lib = require('myLib')
const language = lib.getMyLang()
module.exports = {
    "type": "lib.getType(language)",
    "info": "lib.getInfo(language)",
    "title": "lib.getTitle(language)"
}
```

The whole script is really large, this specific part I did like:

```
object[key] = "lib.getType(language)";
```

How can I generate the files right and not as strings?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const test = require('./myLib');
const lang = test.language;

const obj = {};
for (const key in test) {
    if (typeof test[key] == 'function') {
        let tempKey = key.toLocaleLowerCase().replace('get', '')
        obj[tempKey] = test[key](lang)
    }
}

module.exports = obj;
```